# Center div; not working well

Tags: html, css

I have read through many posts on this site and other things on the internet about centering a div.

To the left of my div there's a white space that I can't fix.

Here's the Jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ZYfaY/

So far I have tried

```
div#navigation-head{
background-image:url('img/head.png');
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 2em;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left:auto;
right:auto;
```

}

Comment: Another alternative for centering a div would be to use `margin: auto;` that avoids the whole `position: fixed;` which can be a real pain for dynamically sized content, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the default padding the browser adds to the `body` tag.

You can zero this out, by doing

```
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

Or better yet, use a reset stylesheet before your main styles, that way you're working from a consistent base-line - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYfaY/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the basic padding and margin from your html use this

```
body{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Example is here http://jsfiddle.net/ZYfaY/3/

Answer (score 0):

Most of the elements have default properties, product of UA's stylesheet (where UA means User Agent). If you inspect the `body` element, for example, you'll see that he has properties by default.

You have to ***reset*** those properties.

A good practice is including a Reset CSS.

For example:

```
/* Reset CSS */

body, div, section, nav, ... {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

a { text-decoration: none; } /* If you will eliminate the underline for all `a` elements */

/* The rest of reset properties */
```

How to include a ***Reset CSS***?

One option is "call him" in the `head` element:

```
<head>
 <!-- I assume that reset.css is in *css folder* -->
 <style>
  @import url("css/reset.css") screen
  @import url("css/style.css") screen
 </style>
</head>
```

Or "call him" from your principal stylesheet, for example:

```
/* Style CSS */

@import url("reset.css") screen; /* I assume that style.css and reset.css are in the same folder */
```

---

Your problem is that in your code, your body have a margin by default and you didn't reset that default property. You have to eliminate putting:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYfaY/5/)

Be good,
Leonardo